# How to show different photo filter options when user tapped on index 0 to 1 using core data with swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data, uicollectionview

Help I have two UICollectionView, the first collection view is the label where the user can tap it if they want more variety of filters and the second collection view is the place of the filters. I am trying to show 11 filters When user tapped on index 0 (it's the first label I put on the first collection view) and 7 Filters when user tapped index 1 (it's the second label I put on the first collection view) I don't know why it doesn't works and it just give same result (7 filters) even when both index tapped. This is the code I am working on: this my core data class:

```
import Foundation

import CoreData

class CoreDataSeeder { var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
//Look this up
self.managedObjectContext = context
}

func seedCoreData() {
var sepia = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Filter",      inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Filter
sepia.name = "CISepiaTone"

var gaussianBlur = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Filter", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Filter
gaussianBlur.name = "CIGaussianBlur"
gaussianBlur.favorited = true

var colorMap = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Filter", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Filter
colorMap.name = "CIColorMonochrome"

var gammaAdjust = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Filter", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Filter
gammaAdjust.name = "CIColorMap"

var exposureAdjust = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Filter", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Filter
exposureAdjust.name = "CIExposureAdjust"

var effectChrome = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Filter", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Filter
effectChrome.name = "CIPhotoEffectChrome"

 var effectInstant = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Filter", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Filter
effectInstant.name = "CIPhotoEffectInstant"

var effectMono = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Filter", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Filter
effectMono.name = "CIPhotoEffectMono"

var effectNoir = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Filter", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Filter
effectNoir.name = "CIPhotoEffectNoir"

var effectTransfer = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Filter", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Filter
effectTransfer.name = "CIPhotoEffectTransfer"

var effectBloom = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Filter", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Filter
effectBloom.name = "CIBloom"

var error: NSError?
//& is actually memory address, instead of pointer
self.managedObjectContext?.save(&error)

if error != nil {
    println(error?.localizedDescription)
}
}

func seedCoreDataTwo() {
var sepia = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Filter", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Filter
sepia.name = "CISepiaTone"

var gaussianBlur = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Filter", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Filter
gaussianBlur.name = "CIGaussianBlur"
gaussianBlur.favorited = true


var gammaAdjust = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Filter", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Filter
gammaAdjust.name = "CIColorMap"

var effectMono = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Filter", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Filter
effectMono.name = "CIPhotoEffectMono"

var effectNoir = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Filter", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Filter
effectNoir.name = "CIPhotoEffectNoir"

var effectTransfer = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Filter", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Filter
effectTransfer.name = "CIPhotoEffectTransfer"

var effectBloom = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Filter", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Filter
effectBloom.name = "CIBloom"




var error: NSError?
//& is actually memory address, instead of pointer
self.managedObjectContext?.save(&error)

if error != nil {
    println(error?.localizedDescription)
 }
 }

 }
```

inside of the viewcontroller:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
println("bosen kelima")
if (collectionView == self.collectionView) {
    println("First Content")
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("FILTER_CELL", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FilterThumbnailCell
    var filterThumbnail = self.filterThumbnails[indexPath.row] // this one through bottom of this function will be deleted and moved to "didSelectItemAtIndexPath"
    cell.filterTitle.text = filterThumbnail.filterName
    //Lazy Loading
    if cell.viewWithTag(1) == nil {
    if filterThumbnail.filteredThumbnail != nil {
        cell.imageView.image = filterThumbnail.filteredThumbnail
    } else {
        cell.imageView.image = filterThumbnail.originalThumbnail
        //filterThumbnail is a class instance
        filterThumbnail.generateThumbnail({ (image) -> Void in
            if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? FilterThumbnailCell {
                cell.imageView.image = image
            }
        })
    }
   }
    return cell
   }
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("DRUM", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TextViewCell
cell.textOptionsLabel.text = textOptions[indexPath.row] // It will print Desire, Nature, Bloom
    return cell

  }
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,          shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
if (collectionView == self.collectionView){
let filteredImageSelected = self.filterThumbnails[indexPath.row] //One

//When user does not pick any other photo options, self.unFilteredImage is what is on screen.
if self.unFilteredImage == nil {
    self.unFilteredImage = self.imageView.image
}
 //Pass in unfiltered photo so filter will not keep building
    filteredImageSelected.filterImage(self.unFilteredImage!, completionHandler: { (filteredImage) -> Void in
        self.imageView!.image = filteredImage //Two
    })
}
    if (collectionView == self.secondCollectionView){
        println("shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath Clicked")
        if ((indexPath.row)==0){
            println("index number 1 Clicked")

           /* self.generateThumbnail()

            //Setting up GPU Context
            var options = [kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: NSNull()]
            var myEAGLContext = EAGLContext(API: EAGLRenderingAPI.OpenGLES2)
            self.context = CIContext(EAGLContext: myEAGLContext, options: options)*/

            var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            //Did this in CoreDataSeeder.swift
            self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

            //Seeding Core Data
            var seeder = CoreDataSeeder(context: appDelegate.managedObjectContext!)

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Filter")
            var error: NSError?
            if let filters = self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [Filter] {
                if filters.isEmpty {
                    seeder.seedCoreData()
                    self.filters = self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as! [Filter]
                } else {
                    self.filters = filters
                }
            }
            println("Number of filters view did load: \(filters.count)")
            self.resetFilterThumbnails()
            self.collectionView.delegate = self //Try to make another collection view and data source to trigger
            self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        }
if ((indexPath.row)==1) {
            self.generateThumbnail()

            //Setting up GPU Context
            var options = [kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: NSNull()]
            var myEAGLContext = EAGLContext(API: EAGLRenderingAPI.OpenGLES2)
            self.context = CIContext(EAGLContext: myEAGLContext, options: options)

            var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            //Did this in CoreDataSeeder.swift
            self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

            //Seeding Core Data
            var seeder = CoreDataSeeder(context: appDelegate.managedObjectContext!)

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Filter")
            var error: NSError?
            if let filters = self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [Filter] {
                if filters.isEmpty {
                    seeder.seedCoreDataTwo()
                    self.filters = self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as! [Filter]
                } else {
                    self.filters = filters
                }
            }//Try find a way to move this to cellforindexpath

            println("Number of filters view did load: \(filters.count)")
            self.resetFilterThumbnails()
            self.collectionView.delegate = self //Try to make another collection view and data source to trigger
            self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        }

    }
return false
}
```

Is there anyway to make it works ? I would appreciate it if you could help me

Comment: I don't understand why you use CoreData for this. You don't need it, especially when you don't know how to use it well. Just use 2 array with Strings for your filter names.

Answer (score 0):

You add all those objects to CoreData in two steps but I don't see you made any way to be able to retrieve them separately. It doesn't matter that you add them in 2 functions, they all go to the same place.

What you need to do is add a property to you objects: say "group", and set it to 1 for the first group and 2 for the second. And then when you fetch them from CoreData to display them you filter them based on the group you want to get.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't complete, you can take a look again the code above @pteofil

Comment: I guess my mistake is make same code on index 0 and 1, except I call seeder.seedCoreData() on index 0 and seeder.seedCoreDataTwo() on index 1 @pteofil